# Injecting into knex method chain

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Here's what I'm doing now

```
const branchA = q =>
  q.join(...joinParams);

const branchB = (q, params) =>
  q.joinRaw('weird join')
   .join(...params)
   .groupBy('name');


const q = knex('user').where(condition);

if (bool) {
  return branchA(q);
}
else {
  return branchB(q, params);
}
```

I would like my code to look more functional-styled. I'm looking for something like:

```
knex('user').where(condition).inject(q => bool ? queryBranchA(q) : branchB(q, params));
```

That "inject" is what I can't find in knex docs.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for `.modify()` it is found from https://knexjs.org/ ,but it seems to be missing from sidebar.

Added issue to documentation about it: https://github.com/knex/documentation/issues/146